# GET FORM not working with .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller, get, submit

Im using  PHP MVC (im new in that MVC) i have a file `.htaccess` where I wrote this code

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

I also have a controller

```
class Enlaces{

    public function enlacesController(){

        if(isset($_GET["action"])){

            $enlaces = $_GET["action"];
        }else{

            $enlaces = "index";
        }

        $respuesta = EnlacesModels::enlacesModel($enlaces);
        include $respuesta;
    }
}
```

This is the model

```
class EnlacesModels{

    public function enlacesModel($enlaces){

        switch ($enlaces) { 
            case 'captura':             
                $module = "vistas/modulos/padron/".$enlaces.".php";
                return $module;
                break;
            case 'inicio':
            case 'ingreso':
                $module = "vistas/modulos/".$enlaces.".php";        
                return $module;
                break;  
            case 'index':
                $module = "vistas/modulos/ingreso.php";     
                return $module;
                break;                                                                      
            default:
                $module = "vistas/modulos/ingreso.php";
                return $module;
                break;
        } 
    }
}
```

I need to use a form where I need to obtain value of inputs with GET, but it's not possible by the uses of `.htaccess` & Controller & model that I mentioned, when I submit the form I obtained the following URL

```
http://localhost/caiga20/captura?search_apat=morghen&search_amat=&search_ife=
```

It shows a "?" beside "&" I think that is the reason that I can not found the value when I tried to get it

Appreciate your help, the following is form code:

```
  <div class="row">
      <form method="GET">
      <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">           
          <label for="search_apat"> A Paterno: </label>
          <input id="search_apat" name="search_apat" class="form-control search_apat" type="search"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
          <label for="search_amat"> A Materno: </label>
          <input id="search_amat" name="search_amat" class="form-control search_amat" type="search"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-10">
          <label for="search_ife"> Clave Elector: </label>
          <input id="search_ife" name="search_ife" class="form-control search_ife" type="search"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-2">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <a href="#">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">                
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
              </button>
            </a>
          </span>                                  
        </div>   
      </div>  
      </form>                  
  </div>
```

Comment: What is $action supposed to capture, the url or the query string? It’s capturing both. Try putting in die($action); in the controller to prove or disprove what you think is being passed

Comment: On second thought, my suggestion to print $action will be inconclusive, because action will not get a good value passed to it. What I should have asked you to do is to explain in detail what Htaccess is capturing and why. When you explain the why, the problem will become evident.